# How do I run compiled C++ code using ```"./path/to/file"``` in ```.bashrc``` on raspberry pi?

Tags: bash

I tried to compile a c++ program using gcc on raspberry pi and the code runs fine if i run it from a terminal with `"./path/to/file"`. If i copy and save the same command to `.bashrc` file and restart the machine i get an error saying "no such file or directory". Can someone help. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the `path/to/file` relative to? It should work if it's from your home directory. If it doesn't, try an absolute path.

Comment: i start from root which in my case will be /home/pi/Desktop/executable_file. is the period required before the path in bashrc to execute the program?

Comment: `cd /to/place/where/path/is/relative/to && ./path/to/file` will run `/to/place/where/path/is/relative/to/path/to/file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certain that your PATH is not finding the file because you're using a "relative" path (starting with `./`).  Instead, change the .bashrc file to point to the full path to the file (something like `/home/pi/path/to/file`).

Comment: removed period, worked fine. thanks.